# What method should I use to solve this integral?

Tags: integration

I have no clue how to solve it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

$$ \int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\cos^3\left(x\right)\sin^5\left(x\right)}}dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Express both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ through $\tan x$ and $\sec x$.
$$\sin x = \frac{\tan x}{\sec x}, \qquad \cos x = \frac{1}{\sec x}$$
After some simplifications, you can set $t = \tan x$.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

**Generalization**:

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{\sin^mx\cos^{2n-m}x} =\int\dfrac{\sec^{2n-2}x}{\tan^mx}\sec^2x\ dx$$

Now choose $\tan x=u$

Can you recognize $m,n$  here?

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me!