# Question about an integration problem to solve in different ways.

Tags: integration, trigonometry

[integration problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sex6s.jpg)

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin x}\sqrt{\cos^7x}}=\int\frac{\frac{dx}{\cos^4x}}{\frac{\sqrt{\sin x}\sqrt{\cos^7x}}{\cos^4x}}$$
$$=\dots=2\sqrt{\tan x}+\frac25\sqrt{\tan^5x}+C$$

So, I've solved the problem in this way. I found a rule in our text book that if sin and cos are in denominator in multiplied form, then we should divide the numerator and denominator by cos^(summation of the powers of sin and cos). But is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Please next time take the pain to type instead of inserting a link (I did it for you).

Comment: Understood! Thanks.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4392730/calculating-int-fracdx-sqrt3x12x-17   and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070289/what-method-should-i-use-to-solve-this-integral

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $u=\sqrt{\tan x},$ $\frac{dx}{\cos^2x}=2udu$:
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\sin x\cos^7x}}=2\int(1+u^4)du=\dots.$$

Comment: So..... How did you simplified that trigonometry part before substituting u?

Comment: I did not simplify *before*. I just *meanwhile* replaced $\frac{dx}{u\cos^4x}$ by $\frac{2du}{\cos^2x}=2(1+u^4)du.$

Answer (score 0):

the integrand is invariant by $x\rightarrow x+\pi$. Even if it's not a rationnal fraction one may hope Bioche rules to give a good substitution here $u=\tan x$
$$I=\int{1+u^2\over\sqrt u}du=2\sqrt u+\frac25u^{5/2}$$